# React-bootstrap : popup modal open when we click on login menu

Tags: reactjs

I have the component shown below. I want to open React-bootstrap Modal popup when I click on "Login" menu:

```
export default class Navigation extends Component
{
  render() {
    return (
        <Navbar fixedTop inverse collapseOnSelect className="menu">
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                        <a href="#"><Image src="Logo.png" alt="Ubibird" responsive/></a> 
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Navbar.Form pullLeft>
                    <form>
                        <FormGroup id="search"> 
                            <InputGroup>
                                <InputGroup.Addon className="glysearch"> <Glyphicon glyph="search" /></InputGroup.Addon> 
                                <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                            </InputGroup>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
                </Navbar.Form>
                <Nav pullRight>
                    **<NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Login</NavItem>**
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Sign Up</NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Modal? Is it in another component? Can you add the code for the Modal?

Comment: yes in another file named : loginpop.js and i have copy and pasted code from here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

You don't clarify which Modal component you have in your code, so here's the full solution:

You need a separate component that renders the Bootstrap modal. The code would be:

```
constructor(props, context) {
  this.state = {show: false};
}

open = () => {
  this.setState({show: true});
}

close = () => {
  this.setState({show: false});
}

render() {
  return (
    <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.close}>
      ...
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Then in your Navigation component you need to import and render the Modal somewhere. Then add a `onClick` listener to your button handle the opening of the modal:

```
openLoginModal = () => {
  this.refs.loginModal.open();
}

render() {
  return (
   ...
   <NavItem ref="loginModal" eventKey={1} href="#" onClick={this.openLoginModal}>Login</NavItem>
   ...
  );
}
```